# Delphi XE and Chromium Embedded Framework running slow under win 7 32 bit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, chromium, chromium-embedded

We're using a delphi built application using CEF (1650) and experiencing compatibility issues when running in Windows 7 32 bit OS.    The 32 bit app works fine under Win 7 64 bit, our preferred environment, but when run on our vendor's 32 bit Win 7 machines it runs horribly slow until XP service pack 3 compatibility mode is selected.   We've ruled out the EXE itself as the culprit but suspect it may be the CEF libraries.   Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is that you perform some profiling and debugging. It runs slowly? So find out where it is spending the time.

Comment: It turns out that onn a clean copy of Win7 32 bit the application runs perfectly fine.  It's something unique to the configuration on my vendor's machines.  I'm following up with them.